# Removing stuck named range on a xlsm file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I got a `.xlsm` file with some kind of problem. When I open it on Excel 2010, it shows the following message:

[image: First Message]

It translates:

> Excel found unreadable content in "Checklists.xlsm". Do you want to retrieve the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

When I click yes, it show the following:

[image: Second Message]

It translates:

> Excel could not open the file by repairing or removing unreadable content.
>
> Excel has completed repairing and validation at file level. Maybe some parts of the workbook may have been repaired or discarded.
>
> Records Removed: Named Range from /xl/workbook.xml (Workbook)

So checked every named range on file and I spotted one that was missing. So I tried to recreate it and I got the following message:

[image: Third Message]

> The name you entered is not valid.
>
> Possible Reasons:
>
> - Name starts with a letter or underscore
> - Name contains a space or other invalid characters
> - The name conflicts with an Excel internal name or the name of another object in the workbook.

Since the name was created before but now I can't create it, I'm presuming it's inside the file, but somehow I can't access it. I tried to list that locked named range with the following code in VBA:

```
Sub ShowNames()
    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
        MsgBox(n.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

But it doesn't showed the name I put before. So I unzipped the file and I run `grep -R thatNamedRange *` over the contents. It showed nothing on corrected file, but it still appears on old one.

So I'm stuck here, trying to remove this old named range in order to solve it. How can I remove this old named range inside the file?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this link: https://superuser.com/questions/1514650/removing-stuck-named-range-on-a-xlsm-file This was really useful

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that's not quite an answer, but I solved using a workaround, because, I don't know really why, I coudn't create a named range on D28:K28 on a sheet called Lookup Table, but it worked when the named range begun with an underscore. `_`

If anybody that knows Excel's internals knows the reason for this, please let me know!